# The server closed the connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to Node.js and MySql but im receiving this error :

> :Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. my code here.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var config = {
    connectionLimit: 100,
    waitForConnections: true,
    queueLimit: 0,
    debug: true,
    wait_timeout: 28800,
    connect_timeout: 10,
    host: "localhost",
    user: " root ",
    password: " root ",
    database: "mydb"
};
var table = 'mytable';
var connection;

function handleConnection() {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        console.log("connected");
    });
    connection.query('select * from' + table,
        function(err, result, fields) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("result :" + result);
            } else {
                console.log("error1 :" + err);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: what is wait_timeout..?
and why haven't  you written connectTimeout instead of connect_timeout..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in your code

> connection.query('select * from' + table,

Will resolve to the following:

> select * frommytable

As there is no space after the 'from' keyword. Try adding a space character after 'from'.

Also in the config, you're adding a space character before and after the values for user and password:

> user     : " root ", password : " root ",

Comment: after changing that line to : connection.query('select * from mytable',..still im receiving that error

Comment: Your user and password fields also have spaces before and after. Is that correct? Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Finally I found it..My XAMPP is not installed properly.

Comment: @Gayathri glad you got it sorted

Comment: Thanks for your help...:)